# Django database: sorting by field in latest object in relative database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two db tables in django: "Device" table to store actual devices and "DeviceTest" table to store test checks for each device (Many Tests to one Device).

```
class Device(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + " - " + self.serial_number

class DeviceTest(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    TEST_OK = '+'
    TEST_ERROR = '-'
    TEST_RESULT_CHOICES = (
        (TEST_OK, 'Test Success'),
        (TEST_ERROR, 'Test Error'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TEST_RESULT_CHOICES, default=TEST_ERROR)

    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    tester = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.device.name + " - " + \
                self.device.serial_number + " - " + \
                unicode(self.created_at) + " - " + \
                u"Result (" + self.status + ")"
```

I've made HTML page with table of all devices in format:

```
name | serial number | created_at | last_test_time | last_test_status | hyperlink to test table page
```

Now I want to give user all sorting possibilities. I've done that through GET parameters for "name", "serial number" and "created_at" fields. And now I'm stuck with "last_test_time" and "last_test_status" fields.

Can this problem be solved with some standard Django functions? Something like `Device.objects.all().filter(???).order_by(???)`

Comment: [Documentation on queryset ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by). If you are using django rest framework, ordering by fields from query parameter is already implemented.

Comment: Do you mean something like this, `Device.objects.order_by('devicetest_set__created','devicetest_set.status)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates) the queryset with the latest `created_at` time.

```
from django.db.models import Max

queryset = Device.objects.annotate(last_test_time=Max('devicetest__created_at'))
```

You can access `last_test_time` for each object.

```
for obj in queryset
    print(obj.last_test_time)
```

And you can order the queryset by this field

```
queryset = queryset.order_by('last_test_time')
```

However, this is only a partial answer, because it does not help you get the status of that test.

You could do a lookup for each device individually.

```
for device in queryset:
    device.latest_status = device.device_test.latest('created_at').status
```

This is ok if the number of devices is small, but it means one query for each device, which isn't ideal as the number of devices increases.

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) to fetch all the related device tests in one query. (the code below is untested, I might have the syntax slightly wrong).

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('devicetest', DeviceTest.objects.order_by('-created_at'))
```

You can then get the status via the first related device test.

```
for obj in queryset:
    print obj.devicetest.all()[0].status
```

Note this is inefficient, because you have loaded all related items, not just the most recent one.

Comment: It depends on which model do you care about more. If you care more about the `DeviceTest`, you could do `DeviceTest.objects.annotate(latest_test_time=Max('created_at')).order_by('-latest_test_time')`.

Comment: Ah yea, just realized that. Do you know the syntax?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks! Sorting by last_test_time works exactly as it should! Haven't try the second part about last_test_status sorting yet. Also I've seen "latest" function in django docs, could it be used somehow in this situation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: The `latest()` method returns the latest item in a queryset, you want the latest related item for *each device* in the queryset. You could loop through the queryset and use latest for each device (I've added an example above), but that means one sql query for every device, which isn't ideal.